# Microsoft edge is not prompting for user authentication

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

I have an angular js application, which is working perfectly fine in IE/Chrome. But i see that in Microsoft Edge browser it is opening the web portal, but on clicking other pages which requires windows authentication, it is not showing the credential window pop-up. "HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication." Console error is displayed. Whereas this is working as expected in other browsers like IE/Chrome. web.config file is used for enabling user authentication for few pages in a web portal application. Does anyone know why Edge is behaving different?

Comment: Can you please inform which version of MS Edge browser you are using for making this test? I found that some users had this complain for a older version (EDGE 41). If you are using any older version of MS Edge browser than I suggest you to install the latest updates for Edge browser and again make a test may help to solve the issue. Further, you can try to clear all the cache and permissions for that site and make a test again.

Comment: 40.15063.674.0 Edge version I'm using.

Comment: Edge 40 is too old and outdated. current latest version is Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 I suggest you to update your Windows OS with latest updates may help to update your Edge browser with the latest version. than you can try to make a test with the latest version of Edge to check whether it helps to fix the issue or not. Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions, if needed.